# footer in print page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i have an html page need to print.

```
<div>content to print</div>
```

also im having a footer content like

```
<div class="divFooter" style="clear: both; text-align: center, font-size: 12px;">
    footer content
</div>
```

CSS for footer is

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen
    {
        div.divFooter
        {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    @media print
    {
        div.divFooter
        {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

the footer is aligned at the bottom in ie and firefox.but not working good in chrome browser.Any idea?

Comment: why are you using @media?

Comment: Usman it is special feature for css which is applied while printing and other when you write @media print{} this css only applied when you are printing the page.

Comment: ya i know @ krshekhar i am ust asking @Anilkumar that he knows the concept. bcoz he is saying it is not working in chrome.

Comment: yes usman,its not working in chrome

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `@media print` tag. then your footer will be at bottom in `print preview`. If you want footer at bottom in browser then add `@media all`.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen
    {
        div.divFooter
        {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    @media all
    {
        div.divFooter
        {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```